# Computing an expression tree recursively

Tags: c++, binary-tree, expression-trees

I built a function that takes my expression tree and computes the values. My leaf nodes are either number or letters as keys, but have integers as their values. When I run the program, I get -74 as my answer, which is not correct. Any clue on where the error is?

```
                    -
                  /   \
                 +     *
               /  \   /  \
              a   /   2   +
                 / \     / \
                *       e   3
               / \
              b   c



 class bt
    {public:

        bt()
        {
        root = new tnode('-', 3, NULL);
        root->left = new tnode('+', 5, root);
        root->left->left = new tnode('a', 3, root->left);
        root->left->right = new tnode('/', 5, root->left);
        root->left->right->left = new tnode('*', 2, root->left->right);
        root->left->right->right = new tnode('d', 11, root->left->right);
        root->left->right->left->left = new tnode('b', 3, root->left->right->left);
        root->left->right->left->right = new tnode('c', 7, root->left->right->left);
        root->right = new tnode('*', 3, root);
        root->right->left = new tnode('2', 6, root->right);
        root->right->right = new tnode ('+', 1, root->right);
        root->right->right->left = new tnode ('e', 10, root->right->right);
        root->right->right->right = new tnode ('3', 3, root->right->right);
        }
  int calc(tnode *t)

{
    if(t->left==NULL && t->right == NULL)
    return t->value;
    else
    {
        int answer = 0;
        switch(t->key)
        {
            case '+':
                answer = calc(t->left)+calc(t->right);
                break;
            case '-':
                answer = calc(t->left)-calc(t->right);
                break;
            case '*':
                answer = calc(t->left)*calc(t->right);
                break;
            case '/':
                answer = calc(t->left)/calc(t->right);
                break;
        }
    return answer;  
    }
}
```

And my node class

```
#ifndef tnode_H
#define tnode_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class tnode
{
public:
    tnode(char key, int value, tnode* p)
    {
                this->key = key;
                this->value = value;
                n = 1;
                left = NULL;
                right = NULL;
                parent = p;
    }


        tnode* left;
        tnode* right;
        tnode* parent;
        char key;
        int value;
        int n;

};




#endif
```

Comment: The answer depends on what the values are. Also, have you stepped through the program with a debugger?

Comment: My guess is it's something with how you build the tree.

Comment: And where are you *hashing* letters into values?

Comment: Let me update my code

Comment: When my function "Return t->value", it's getting the numerical value for the particular node

Comment: What's wrong with the answer? (3+21/11)-(6*(10+3)) integer arithmetic = 4-6*13 = -74

Comment: You are aware, I suppose that your drawn graph of the tree and the actual tree are different?

Comment: The tree you are building does not match the picture.

Comment: @brianbeuning It's missing a `d` node for the division, otherwise it seems to match. What makes it hard to follow is that the node called `2` for example has the value `6`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The eval code allows a node to be either an operator or an integer literal, the node('*', 2,..) tries to be both.